# how to know when database became empty in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am makin a quiz in php and mysql . now i am fetching the questions from database, suppose if i don't know the no of questions in the datbase. i want my code to fetch the data till questions are not over, but i don't the no of questions which are there . so which condtion will be applicable . code which is fetching data .

```
<?php

 function ravi($qid=NULL)
 {              

            $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or          die(mysql_error());
            $db = mysql_select_db('quiz', $con) or die(mysql_error());
            $q="select * from question where qno=$qid";
            $rq=mysql_query($q,$con);
            if(!$rq)
            {
            echo " the sql query faiiled to work ";
            }
            else
            {

            while ($sub_row=mysql_fetch_array($rq))
            {
            $id=$sub_row["qno"];
            $question=$sub_row["question"];
            $option1=$sub_row["option1"];
            $option2=$sub_row["option2"];
            $option3=$sub_row["option3"];
            $option4=$sub_row["option4"];


            echo "<h5>Q".$id." : ".$question."</br></h5>";   
            echo"</br>
                <br>

                <h4><input type= radio id='1' name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option1}\">$option1</h4>
                </br>

                <h4><input type= radio id='2' name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option2}\">$option2</h4>
                </br>

                <h4><input type= radio id='3' name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option3}\">$option3</h4>
                </br>

                <h4><input type= radio id='4' name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option4}\">$option4</h4>
                </br></br>";
                }
          }}

                    ?>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($rq) == 0) {
    echo "database is empty.";
}
```

But you really should stop using `mysql_*` as has been said in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

To enhance security greatly you should use `mysqli` which is using prepared statements (auto-escaped typecasted variables), [PHP webpage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Something like this:

```
# Database credentials
$mysqlsrv = "localhost";
$mysqlusr = "myusr";
$mysqlpsw = "mypsw";
$mysqldb  = "mydb";

# Connect to database in the secure "prepared statement" way
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysqlsrv,$mysqlusr,$mysqlpsw,$mysqldb);

# Check for database connection errors
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Cannot connect to database";
    exit();
}

$searchNum = 1;
$searchStr = "Text";

$query = "SELECT question FROM mytable WHERE num=? OR str=?";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("is",$searchNum,$searchStr);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($question);

    if($stmt->fetch()) {
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "$question<br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Could not find any post in table";
    } // if($stmt->fetch())

    $stmt->close();
} // if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))
```